# Ruby on Rails IP-Address handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attributes

I didn't find anything on the internet. I wonder what's the best way to handle a model with an IP-Address attribute. I set the DB column type to BIGINT but I don't know how to deal with that in my form. I want the IP automatically converted into a bigint. I am using formtastic. Do I have to write getters/setters?

Comment: switch to postgres and use the ip datatype

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html

Comment: IPAddr.new(4294967295, Socket::AF_INET).to_s is giving 255.255.255.2555

Comment: yeah I know, so I have to write getters and setters? or is better to handle this in the controller?

Comment: inside model is fine. but why not using postgres? postgres is doing really good in stuff like that. its not more difficult as mysql, is the same easy installation

Comment: cause I am not the only one who uses this mysql database

Comment: why dont you save it as a string ?

Comment: strings take too long to work with. I wrote override getters and setters now, but I don't know how to make it work with formtastic, because it reads the value from the database and not form the custom getter